# Hide/Show conditional based on if there is an asterisk in the price?

Tags: jquery, function, hide, show

I'm trying to hide or show a div based on if there is an Asterisk next to the price on a checkout screen using **Jquery**. If there is an Asterisk next to the price then it would display, if there is not an Asterisk it would not display.

Update**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if ('.not-discountable') {
    $('.disclaimer').remove();
}
```

});

I'm trying to say if the .not-discountable div does not exist then the disclaimer will not display.

Comment: Works fine for me. Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/Hjdnw/1359/

Can you share your html snippet too?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't get it at all. But I think this would do the trick:

```
    var price = "*";
    if(price.indexOf('*') > -1){ 
//do your hide thing
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using jQuery.

```
if ( !jQuery('.not-discountable').length ) {  //If there are not .not-discountable elements
    jQuery('.disclaimer').hide();   //hide the disclaimer object };
```

Thanks everybody!